# How can I set the number of copies equal to the amount in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, reportviewer

I have a Datagridview which is connected with excel sheets. My Excel sheet is a good receipt which contains the quantity of the items. Now i want to print labels as much as the amount. E.g if i have 10 T shirts, i want to print 10 labels with a 1 in quantity.

I've already tried the following code.

```
        private void btnSingle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingList<LableClass> GoodReceipt= new BindingList<LableClass>();
        GoodReceipt.Add(new LableClass()
    {
       Charge = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString(),
       ItemNr= dataGridView1.SelectedCells[1].Value.ToString(),
       Description= dataGridView1.SelectedCells[2].Value.ToString(),
       Quantity= float.Parse(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[8].Value.ToString())
    });
        LableClassBindingSource.DataSource = GoodReceipt;

        PrinterSettings prtSetting = new PrinterSettings();


        foreach (PaperSize item in prtSetting.PaperSizes)
        {
            if (item.PaperName == "62mm x 29mm")
                prtSetting.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = item;
        }
        PageSettings ps = new PageSettings(prtSetting);
        ps.Landscape = false;

        ps.Margins.Top = 8;
        ps.Margins.Bottom = 0;
        ps.Margins.Left = 6;
        ps.Margins.Right = 0;


        PrintDocument prtDoc = new PrintDocument();

        prtDoc.PrinterSettings = prtSetting;

        prtSetting.Copies = 5;
        prtSetting.FromPage = 1;
        prtSetting.ToPage = 5;
        reportViewer1.SetPageSettings(ps);
        prtDoc.Print();

        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

    }
```

I tried to print 5 labels for a test, but somehow all of them are empty. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: The code posted doesn't contain any properties from the DGV.  Is the DataSource of DGV a DataTable?  If so get number of rows of DataTable : int rows = dt.Rows.Count;

Comment: Sorry my fault. I edited it now

Comment: So isn't the number of items GoodReceipt.Count?

Comment: No GoodReceipt is my list with all the data. My number of item is quantity. This one: float.Parse(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[8].Value.ToString()). I want to print as many as i have quantity in my excel sheet.

Comment: What about : int count = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count;